# ConnectionString Jet.OLEDB.4.0 | read Localdb from serverside

Tags: sql-server, database, connection-string, oledb, local

I have following

```
ConnectionString='Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\db\;Persist Security Info=False;Extended Properties="dBASE IV"'
ProviderName="System.Data.OleDb" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ABC]"
```

This works fine as long I work local. My question is can I use a ConnectionString like this from serverside geting to the local (C:\db) file?

Comment: you should use `UNC` path if it is a shared drive

Comment: something like **'Uri(@"C:\db\")'** ?

Comment: @ Rene, it should be path like "servername\sharename\directory\", your `C:\db` can only be recognized by your local machine. Can you point the connection to the database on the server?